# Python 3: Attempting to iterate thru csv file and write contents to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to read each line of the csv file below.

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbk62.png)

I would like to extract the data from each row and append to a new text file.

Here is the code i use to read the csv file:

```
#Count number of lines in the csv file
cnd = datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%y")
df = pd.read_csv(cnd+'sr.csv')
numline = len(df)
ma = df['Make'][:numline]
mo = df['Model'][:numline]
yr = df['Year'][:numline]
cl = df['Color'][:numline]
pr = df['Price'][:numline]


#For loop to break the csv file into 10 lines at a time
for x in range(0,numline,10):
    if x < 10:
        mk = ma[:10]
        mod = mo[:10]
        ye = yr[:10]
        clr = cl[:10]
        prc = pr[:10]
```

I'm using the snippet of code below to create the new text file, extract the data from the csv file and appended the data to the new text file. The problem lies in the 3rd block of code.

```
#Create text File
facts = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y-%H%M%S.txt")
f = open(facts, 'w+')

#Write generic Title
f.write('Car Facts' + '\r')
f.close()                     
            
#Open the text file. Iterate thru each line of the csv file and append to the text file
of = open(facts, "a")
    for k in mk:
        for m in mod:
            for y in ye:
                for c in clr:
                    for p in prc:
                         of.write('\r' + 'Make: ' + str(k) + '\r' + 'Model: ' + str(m) + '\r' + 'Year: ' + str(y) + '\r' + 'Color: ' + str(c) + '\r' + 'Price: ' + str(p) + '\r')       
of.close()
```

I end up with a text file that has about 30 blocks of random combinations.
The very first and last block written to the text file are correct.
Everything else in between is just random combinations that i don't need.

How can I fix the code to get the desired end result below?

Thank you

```
Car Facts

Make: Ford
Model: Bronco
Year: 1978
Color: Blue
Price: $24,000.00

Make: Land Rover
Model: Defender
Year: 1985
Color: Black
Price: $21,000.00
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Where do you read your csv file? `mk/mod/ye/clr/prc` are not defined in your snippet.

Comment: I assume those variables are collections. Try the `zip` function: `for data in zip(mk,mod,ye,clr,prc): print(data)`

Comment: Hi Maximilian. Here is the snippet i use to read the csv file:

Comment: #Count number of lines in the csv file
cnd = datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%y")
df = pd.read_csv(cnd+'sr.csv')
numline = len(df)
ma = df['Make'][:numline]
mo = df['Model'][:numline]
yr = df['Year'][:numline]
cl = df['Color'][:numline]
pr = df['Price'][:numline]


#For loop to break the csv file into 10 lines at a time
for x in range(0,numline,10):
    if x < 10:
        mk = ma[:10]
        mod = mo[:10]
        ye = yr[:10]
        clr = cl[:10]
        prc = pr[:00]

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Hi AMC, I just copied the cells from the csv file, but stackoverflow only gives me the option to paste it as an image instead of in csv cell format. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This opens the existing CSV file and loops through it while writing the line to the new text file. You might have to manually delete the first entry since it consists of the titles

```
File1 = open("Existing CSV File.csv", "r")
File2 = open("New text file.txt", "w")
for X in File1:
    Line = X.split(",")
    File2.write("Make: " + Line[0] + "\n")
    File2.write("Model: " + Line[1] + "\n")
    File2.write("Year: " + Line[2] + "\n")
    File2.write("Colour: " + Line[3] + "\n")
    File2.write("Price: " + Line[4] + "\n")
    File2.write("")
File1.close()
File2.close()
```

Comment: `Line` is already a list of strings, no need to convert it. Also the output is different than the OP's desired output.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters is that better?

Comment: Thank you Evorage, the output would require some further work.

Comment: Hi Evorage, I have been at this since Saturday night.  Your suggestion was the break through that helped solve my problem. Namely, your use of Line[x] to write the output. I would've never thought to use Line[x] to write the output.  Your input is much appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: @jiro no problem, thats what stackoverflow is for